# Variable position in echo is changing the result

Tags: bash, unix, awk, grep, echo

I used grep to fetch result from two files and store the result in two variable respectively.
while I echo the output of two variable at that time if I change the position of variable then the result is changing .
The scenario is explained below with the example

```
i=123
res1=`grep S$i $NamesFile` 
res2=`grep S$i $FeeInformation|awk '{$1="" ; print $0}'` 
echo "$res1 $res2" ## this prints the value from both variable separated by space 
echo "$res2 $res1" ## in this the variable two override the output of variable one
```

the issue is happening only on my terminal I tested it in other machine it is working fine , even In my terminal it was working till yesterday , don't know what change has happened which impacted this

NameFile contains the information like Student_id Name_of_student Mobile_No Location  Email_id

FeeInformation file contains values Student_id  Class Fee Admission_type(DOnation/Free)

Please suggest what could be the possible reason for this .
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try `nawk` in case of `awk` in some cases it found used too

Comment: nawk is not available at my terminal

Comment: Check your input files for DOS line endings. It appears that a carriage return embedded in `$res2` is causing the cursor to return to the beginning of the line in the second `echo`, at which point `$res1` overwrites the rest of the line.

Comment: Checked the file , could not find any unusual character in the file

Comment: Can u do some  dummy echo after res2 in 1st example. Let's see if that gets overwritten too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the linefeed character \r was causing the issue